# Creating GUI for ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all, i am a pg student working on robotics, i have configured ROS Indigo in my Ubuntu 14.04LTS, also interfaced and drive multiple servo motors using Arduino using ROS package. But till now, to drive servo motor, i was giving command from the terminal window, which i want to drive from the GUI. For this i have created a GUI window in QT, but how to connect this GUI to my ROS package as well as Arduino IDE, i have wasted my lot time to find this. Can anybody help me to find out the solution for this.

I would be very thankful for this task. Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216027/creating-gui-for-ros/) by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably it would be good to make a rqt plugin.
These can be done in Python and CPP.

I guess there is no tutorial but just check for the given plugins:

http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_common_plugins?distro=jade

A good example for a C++ plugin is rqt_imageview, because the most of them are done in python.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on 2015-08-18**:
Is it possible to write a program in QT and then combining it with ROS and ARDUINO?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-08-18**:
It is, take a look at the CMakeLists.txt of the rqt_imageviewer plugin for how to include the QT libraries, you do not have to write a plugin.
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/master/rqt_image_view/CMakeLists.txt